# Apply a function selectively to given columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have following pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dat = pd.DataFrame({'X1': ['aa'], 'X2': [2.3], 'X3': [23.56]})
```

Now I want to apply `numpy.round()` function to selected columns which are chosen by name. Trivially, I can individually pick a particular column by name and apply `numpy.round()` function e.g.

```
dat['X2'] = np.round(dat['X2'], 2)
```

While this is feasible  for a dataframe with smaller number of columns, if the dataframe has hundreds of columns where `numpy.round()` function to be applied, this become cumbersome.

Is there any easier way to achieve this where I just need to supply the column names and `numpy.round()` function will applied directly to them?

Answer (score 3):

pandas allows you to specify a list of columns.

```
cols = ['x2','x4','x9','x11']
dat[cols] = np.round(dat[cols],2)
```

However, I do want to offer a caution.  You should not do rounding like this if you are going to do further computation.  Rounding is only for human eyes, so you should only do this if you are about to display the dataframe or convert it to Excel.  Otherwise, leave the numbers with their full precision.

Comment: Thanks for your warning for using `round` - I agree with that. However, is it possible to implement your solution using `pipe`? I tried with `dat.pipe(lambda x : x[cols] = np.round(x[cols],2))` - but this does not work. Any suggestion is very appreciated

Comment: What's the point?  You haven't gained anything and it doesn't read as well.

Comment: I want to use `pipe` to maintain overall styling and consistency in my whole code. To me, however, applying chain method like `pipe` is more beneficial because, it creates a sequence of actions applied to the original dataframe (but this is my organization's view, other may disagree)

Comment: That's fine if you have a pipeable operation.  This is not.  You don't want a flow here, you want to modify this DataFrame in place.  You're trying to shove a square peg into a round hole.

Answer (score 1):

With many hundreds of columns it may well be tedious to specify all the columns by name in which case ranges of columns can be used. For example: assuming columns 'X2', 'X3' ... to 'X10' exist and are to be rounded:

```
dat.loc[:, 'X2':'X10']=  np.round(dat.loc[:, 'X2':'X10'],2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list as an index, for example:

```
cols = ['X2', 'X3']
dat[cols] = np.round(dat[cols])
dat
```

```
   X1   X2    X3
0  aa  2.0  24.0
```

For more info, see the user guide: [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)